# i am getting warn logs error in logstash when i try to run systemctl restart logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grafana, metricbeat

Could not index event to `Elasticsearch`.

```
 {:status=>400, :action=>[“index”, {:_id=>nil, :_index=>“metricbeat-2019.08.08.02", :_type=>“_doc”, :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x38876a33>], :response=>{“index”=>{“_index”=>“metricbeat-2019.08.08.02", “_type”=>“_doc”, “_id”=>“TGb0bmwBvgRVXMnRZHCA”, “status”=>400, “error”=>{“type”=>“illegal_argument_exception”, “reason”=>“mapper [system.load.1]
```

cannot be changed from type `[float] to [long]“}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

index=>“metricbeat-2019.08.08.02" 
This index format is wrong.
The above index name format is "metricbeat-YYYY-MM-MM-DD"

Instead of that format please use the below format,

index => "metricbeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

or

index => "metricbeat-2019.08.02"

Comment: but my index => "metricbeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd:hh}" i have added with 8th month and 8th day... tats why it is yyy.mm.dd.hh(year.08 th month. 8th date and hour)

Comment: is that the issue i got the error? u want me to remove tat hour?

Comment: if you are trying to give the hour then give colon(:) instead of dot(.), index => "metricbeat-2019.08.08:02"